# How to add Review using REST API in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to find a rest api to add review. But it seems like magento doesn't provide api for that.I created custom api's to get review and rating using:

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/get-review-rating-collection-magento-2.html

But I have no idea how to add review and rating using rest api. Please somebody Help.

Answer (score 0):

This module implement WebAPI for product reviews. Check the repo on Github:
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento2-review-api

Module allow you to:

- Get one review
- Create review with ratings
- Update review with ratings
- Search reviews
- Get product reviews

Comment: DivanteLtd/magento2-review-api is not compatible with PHP 7.3

Comment: Have you checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094172/need-of-create-custom-rest-api-for-reviews-in-magento-2 ?

Comment: I have created a custom API to get all reviews and rating. But couldn't find any sample code to add review and rating using REST API

Comment: I can't find any specific example for reviews, in most of cases people use the linked repo, but you can create your interface in this way https://magecomp.com/blog/create-custom-rest-api-in-magento-2/ and implement your code for get/set/remove your reviews. I think Magento review endpoint will be developed soon.